# Magento: how to merge two collections while inside the Observer?

Tags: magento

I need to reorganize the product listing category page.
I have a *date_field* attribute in my products that need to follow this ranking:

- products with *date_field* >= today appears first
- merge it to products with *date_field* < today

So, I created an observer for *catalog_block_product_list_collection* dispatcher with the following code:

```
$original_collection = clone $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();

$observer->getEvent()->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToFilter('data_inicio', array('gteq' => date('Y-m-d')));

$collection2 = $original_collection
                ->addAttributeToFilter('data_inicio', array('lt' => date('Y-m-d')));

//and after I will merge both collections by adding each item from $collection2 into $observer
```

But when applying the same filter again on *$collection2* it raises the following error:

> You cannot define a correlation name '_table_data_inicio_default' more
>   than once

Only the first part of the filter works fine.
Is there a better way for doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with PHP's clone is it isn't a *deep* clone so some resources are shared, hence the conflicting name you see.  I find a best practice is to do as much work as possible in SQL then these little problems rarely crop up.

```
$collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
// store old ordering
$orderBys = $collection->getSelect()->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER)
$collection->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);

// set first order part
$collection->addExpressionAttributeToSelect(
               'future',
               'IF({{data_inicio}}>="' . date('Y-m-d') . '",1,0)',
               'data_inicio')
           ->addAttributeToSort('future', 'desc');

// reinstate old ordering afterwards
foreach ($orderBys as $orderBy) {
    $collection->getSelect()
        ->order(is_array($orderBy) ? implode(' ', $orderBy) : $orderBy);
}
```

Here, an expression `future` is created to compare the date and then sorted with the today-or-greater rows first.  It is not sorting by `data_inicio`.  It might override any default sort and - I haven't tested for this - might be applied after a user's sort.

Comment: Hi @clockworkgeek. Its a really really great solution. I just cant change the default order by adding the ->addAttributeToSort, right? How can I change the default order in the observer?

Comment: If you set the default order with an `->addAttributeToSort` then it will be fixed and the user won't be able to change it with the 'Sort By' drop-down on the frontend.

Comment: In fact our customized template doesnt allow user to select the sorting order. I saw on the ->getSelect() that the sort is being applied, but after `cat_index_position` and `product_id` as follows: ORDER BY `cat_index_position` asc, `cat_index`.`product_id` asc, IF(IF(_table_data_inicio.value_id > 0, _table_data_inicio.value, _table_data_inicio_default.value)>="2012-09-27",1,0) desc

Comment: I got it! @clockworkgeek I needed to use getSelect()->reset('order') before. =] Thank you very very much.

Comment: I only know of one way to insert an order before other clauses and it isn't pretty, I've updated my answer to show but since you now have it working it's probably not needed.

Answer (score 0):

The *->addExpressionAttributeToSelect()* is the trick!
I had some problems on sorting, because there was other fields being ordered before the observer. So I resetted them...

My code:

```
$observer->getEvent()->getCollection()
    ->addExpressionAttributeToSelect(
        'future',
        'IF({{data_inicio}}="' . date('Y-m-d') . '",2,  IF({{data_inicio}}>="' . date('Y-m-d') . '",1,0))',
        'data_inicio')
    ->getSelect()->reset('order')->order(array('future desc', 'data_inicio asc'));
```

I also added another IF inside and added a second column to sort.

Thanks again @clockworkgeek.